# Drawing two vector at two points parallel to each other

Tags: matlab, math, multidimensional-array, graph, graphics

Consider a vector, A= [0.13, 0.98, 0.05]

How to draw a vector, B which is parallel to A but at points 
P = [155, 156, 52], the origin of vector B.

I tried in MATLAB as follows,

```
pts = [O; A]; %   O= [0 0 0]
line(pts(:,1), pts(:,2), pts(:,3))

B = A*10; % Multiplied B by any scalar (e.g. 10) to get a vector parallel to A  
hold on
pts = [P; B]; % PB vector parallel to OA
line(pts(:,1), pts(:,2), pts(:,3))
```

Would you correct me?

% ****************** More explanation ********

```
         E = cross(B,C);
```

So Three vectors (B, E,C) need to draw at point P. I am totally stuck here

Comment: in your question, A is a vector, are the 3 values coordinates? If so, don't you need 2 pairs of them to create a vector..?

Comment: Yes,  A is a three values coordinates (x,y,z).  I could not catch your points?   Would you let me clear it@GameOfThrows

Comment: your other point is the origin then?

Comment: I would like to draw a new vector which is vector, A or parallel to A at  P considering P as origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the first point of line segment and vector (which defines direction of segment and it's length).

To get the second point, you have to add vector to the first point:

```
pts = [P; P + B];
for your data
P = [155, 156, 52]
B =  [1.3, 9.8, 0.5]
P + B = [156.3, 165.8, 52.5]
```

Some rules of Vector/Point arithmetics:

```
Vector = Point - Point
there is no point addition operation
Point = Point +/- Vector
Vector = Vector +/- Vector
Vector = Scalar * Vector
//more complex rules for multiplication
```

Comment: Would you explain? @MBo

Comment: @Joe Done (I hope)

Comment: I have not done yet. Thanks for the correction. I have edited the question. Please read more explanation in my query- I have added more explanation what I want to do. Sorry for previous post. to MBo

Comment: I don't understand "More explanation". Initial post was clear enough, and I gave full answer. Vector B was parallel to A, now it becomes perpendicular (cross)...

Comment: Probably it would better to describe real problem, not your (probably weird) way to solve it.

Comment: I have corrected the line, 'E = cross(B,C);   Please read only my new post under 'More explanation', forget every thing about previous post. I appreciate your response because I was wrong

Comment: OK, my answer is still valid. You can calculate for drawing endpoint of PB' segment as P+B, and endpoint of PE' segment as P+E. Here B,E are vectors, B',E' are points.